# What's the POST endpoint to broadcast a transaction in copay's server?

Tags: api, server, javascript, copay

AFAIU, copay's server implementation is [bitcore-wallet-service](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-wallet-service).

From its README, I can deduce that a multi-sig wallet will use the [`/v1/txproposals/`](https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-wallet-service/blob/master/lib/model/txproposal.js) endpoint to create a new transaction proposal that the other co-signers will receive.

But, if the wallet is not multi-sig, what's the endpoint for broadcasting a transaction?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multisig and singlesig wallets use the same flow. A Tx proposal need to be created in singlesig wallets also. Copay syncronize across devices, so you can have a non-signing copayers in a 1-1 wallet that submit proposals, for later approval.

The flow is:

create => publish => sign => broadcast.

You can check the official client https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-wallet-client for details, and also the CLI client should be useful to see examples:
https://github.com/bitpay/bitcore-wallet

Answer (score 1):

I think I should leave a comment with a small correction to the flow ematiu posted after 1 day trying to figure out why I couldn't sign my transaction.

the actual flow is:
create => publish => get published => sign => broadcast.

this is because, in order to sign a transaction proposal we need a proposalSignature in the txProposal object. We only get this signature by fetching from the bws

[Bitcore-wallet-client "Server response could not be verified"](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/77160/bitcore-wallet-client-server-response-could-not-be-verified/77175#77175)