# Bitcore-wallet-client "Server response could not be verified"

Tags: client, bitcore, bitpay

I'm getting an error trying to sign a transaction with bitcore-wallet-client.

I create the transaction, publish it and when I try to sign it, I'm getting the error: "SERVER_COMPROMISED - Server response could not be verified"

bws server: https://bws.bitpay.com/bws/api

can anyone point me in the right direction?

ps: using wallet-client (CLI) I can sign the same transaction (created and published from bitcore-wallet-client)

edit: I'm using a testnet account

Comment: Is it the bitcoin core wallet (as in headline) where you have problem, or the API of Bitpay? Maybe adopt the headline?

Comment: so far could track the problem to the bitcore-wallet-client/lib/verifier.js (line 159) where my transaction doesn't have a proposalSignature. To fully answer your question, I'm pretty sure the problem as nothing to do with the API of Bitpay.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I was creating the transaction proposal and publishing it, after that I used the result from createTxProposal and passed it to signTxProposal.

turns out that the txProposal returned from createTxProposal doesn't have the property proposalSignature (which is filled when the transaction is published).

so, to solve this I had to get the transaction proposals (after publishing) and send the transaction fetched as argument to signTxProposal.